# How to fix issue with 'datetime.datetime' which has no attribute timedelta?

Tags: python, datetime

How will I fix this problem on Python. Here's my code:

```
    import time
    import datetime
    from time import mktime
    from datetime import datetime

    date = '20120814174530'
    date_to_strp = time.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S') #convert the value of date into strptime
    date_final = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(date_to_strp))
    #convert date_to_strp so so i can use it to subtract a value from a timedelta later

    date_substracted = date_final - datetime.timedelta(hours = 36)
```

this has an error:

> type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

even though I `import datetime`, I think it was overriden by `from datetime import datetime`, but when I changed the position of `import datetime` and `from datetime import datetime`, the error is:

> 'module' object has no attribute 'fromtimestamp'

I can fix this both error with this code:

```
    import time
    from time import mktime
    from datetime import datetime

    date = '20120814174530'
    date_to_strp = time.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    date_final = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(date_to_strp))

    import datetime

    date_substracted = date_final - datetime.timedelta(hours = 36)
```

Now, with this code it is functioning properly, but what I want is that all import part would be at the top as a good practice, any suggestion on how will i do that without any error with this situation or any suggestion on how will i code it in other way around.

Answer (score 47):

Either use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` or change the import to `from datetime import datetime as dt` and use `dt.fromtimestamp`.

Comment: thank you so much @ecatmur ,i'm not familiar with python that's why i don't know i can use aliasing with the import part... thank you again.

Comment: @obutsu: If this answer helped you solve this problem, you should mark it as accepted answer, not just only thank.

Answer (score 11):

I suppose you should import timedelta separately like this.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta
```

Then you can call

```
dt.fromtimestamp(mktime(date_to_strp))
```

and

```
timedelta(hours = 36)
```

Answer (score 9):

Do not use direct imports like:

```
import decimal
import datetime
```

It will cause:

```
datetime.datetime.today()
decimal.Decimal()
```

Consider this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
print datetime.now()
print Decimal("1")
```